# Enhanced extension methods

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I've create the following extension method which 'highlights' an element once found:

```
public static IWebElement FindElementHighlight(this IWebElement element, By by, IWebDriver driver)
{
    element = driver.FindElement(by);
    if (driver is IJavaScriptExecutor)
    {
        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style.border='3px solid green'", element);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }

    return element;
}
```

The thing is I don't want to use `element.FindElementHighlight(....)`
but I would like to use `driver.FindElementHighlight(....)`

What's the way to modify the extention method so it can be called using driver ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the extension method to extend `IWebDriver` then you need to modify the method signature to start with `this IWebDriver driver`. See the method below.

```
public static IWebElement FindElementHighlight(this IWebDriver driver, By by)
{
    IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(by);

    if (driver is IJavaScriptExecutor)
    {
        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style.border='3px solid green'", element);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }

    return element;
}
```

You call it like

```
IWebElement element = Driver.FindElementHighlight(By.Id("someId"));
```

Comment: Thanks JeffC..That subtle change made it..;-)